# Apply Auto-layout on Independent view

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I have one independent view(green view) on xib and want to set height and width with auto-layout of below green view:

[image]

Note: I don't want to apply Auto-layout with code.

Comment: Can't you use storyboard and insert the green view in controller main view?

Comment: what is your current height and width of that green view and is this view is freeform?

Comment: @lubilis i want to add green view at run time on main view

Comment: @SuhasPatil Actually i want to set green view height and width 50% of the view of main controller.

Comment: then you need to implement this by programmatically, you can not acheive this in xib

Answer (score 1):

you can't set constraints between views which are not related. They must be in the same view hierarchy.
So I believe you can't do it in the interface builder like you want..

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you want without creating a relationship between your "Main View" and your custom view (your green view). Some additional steps are needed:

1. Create a View .xib file (*you already did this*)
2. Design the user interface in Xcode (*it seems you already did this, kind of*)
3. Set up xib's Auto Layout constraints (*in case you will add more stuff inside the green view - these are "internal" constraints*)
4. Create a Swift code file (*For example: CustomView.swift, inheriting from UIView*)
5. Set .xib file’s “File’s Owner” custom class to CustomView (it must match the class name)
6. Implement both CustomView initializers: init(coder:) and
   init(frame:)
7. Load the UIView from the .xib file using the NSBundle and UINib
   classes
8. Add autoresizing masks for the view to match the size of the
   CustomView itself
9. Add your custom view (green view) inside the main view controller and set the desired auto-layout constraints.

[Check this tutorial for a complete working example.](http://supereasyapps.com/blog/2014/12/15/create-an-ibdesignable-uiview-subclass-with-code-from-an-xib-file-in-xcode-6)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add constraints programmatically (or add the view in interface builder and change it's visibility but it's not good). You're trying to set constraints between green view and controller main view, but green view still not know which is its superview. That's not possible from interface builder.